# c# LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var tableID = from data in studyData.Tables["MX_MD_TABLE"].AsEnumerable()
              where data.Field<string>("table_name").ToLower() == "mbddx_study_set"
              select data.Field<long>("ID").ToString();

string tableID = tableID.ElementAt(0).ToString();
```

It works as expected and the tableID is what I want.  Is there a way for the LINQ query to actually return and store the returned string in as it's value, rather than having to create another object to hold it?  I know that this query and a few others I will be doing, will only return the single string.

Thanks.

Comment: That code shouldn't compile - tableID is being declared twice.

Comment: @RQDQ, Correct - I changed that for the purposes of this question to make it clear in context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you want (note the use of [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)):

```
var tableID = (from data in studyData.Tables["MX_MD_TABLE"].AsEnumerable()
          where data.Field<string>("table_name").ToLower() == "mbddx_study_set"
          select data.Field<long>("ID").ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will select the first element found in the table that falls within the desired criteria, as opposed to returning a collection; the `ID`'s of elements ought to be unique anyway so you should only ever be looking for a single one, I'd suspect.

Note that it also returns the value as it's expected type as defined by `Field<long>`, so at this point you just need to call `ToString` on `tableID` after checking it returned something - but don't append it to the `FirstOrDefault` call as that could return null.

Answer (score 0):

```
string tableID  = (from data in studyData.Tables["MX_MD_TABLE"].AsEnumerable()
              where data.Field<string>("table_name").ToLower() == "mbddx_study_set"
              select data.Field<long>("ID").ToString()).ElementAt(0).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tbls.AsEnumerable().Single(o => o.Field<string>("table_name") == "value").Field<long>("ID").ToString();
```

Although I question your use of LINQ on a datatable to return a scalar value.

**Edit:**

LINQ is great and useful and very powerful, but also very expensive.  DataTables have their own built-in way to search for data and return results.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=VS.100).aspx on MSDN for an example.